How does params `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` work when `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` does not have an Add method?
According to the Microsoft documentation on C# 13 features, params collections can be used with types that implement IEnumerable<T> and have an Add method. However, I noticed that I can use IReadOnlyCollection<T> in a params argument, even though IReadOnlyCollection<T> does not have an Add method.
void PrintNumbers(params IReadOnlyCollection<int> numbers)
{
    foreach (var num in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
}

PrintNumbers(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

This code works, and I'm able to pass individual integers to a params parameter of type IReadOnlyCollection<int>
If IReadOnlyCollection<T> doesn't have an Add method, how is it allowed in a params collection?

It probably picks a collection, for example an array, that implements IReadOnlyCollection and uses that.

See on SharpLab decompiled code

The thing that it passes as the argument is not simply an IReadOnlyCollection<int> - rather, it is some compiler-chosen concrete type that implements IReadOnlyCollection<int>, and that type will have Add, or some other mechanism to assign the values. As it happens, the compiler uses int[] (which it subsequently wraps, see below) and RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray when suitable and available, but that is an implementation detail and is up to the compiler to worry about (using considerations such as the target runtime / available utility methods, the size of the data being provided, the types involved, etc).
For example, the code:
static class P
{ 
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo();
        Foo(1, 2, 3);
    }

    static void Foo(params IReadOnlyCollection<int> values) {}
}

is currently interpreted similarly to:
Foo((IReadOnlyCollection<int>)(object)Array.Empty<int>());
int[] array = new int[3];
RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray(array, /* raw metadata token, no C# equiv */);
Foo(new <>z__ReadOnlyArray<int>(array));

where <>z__ReadOnlyArray<T> is a generated wrapper type intended to stop code from casting values back to a int[], and abusing values when they shouldn't be able to. Of course, your code could still abuse reflection, but all bets are off then anyway!

You've excluded a very relevant part of the docs:

The params modifier isn't limited to array types. You can now use
params with any recognized collection type, including System.Span<T>,
System.ReadOnlySpan<T>, and types that implement
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> and have an Add method.


In
addition to concrete types, the interfaces
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>,
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<T>,
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<T>,
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>, and
System.Collections.Generic.IList<T> can also be used.

The requirement for an Add method would be on custom IEnumerable<T> types so that the compiler can ensure that it can insert all the arguments in the collection that it will pass:
void Foo<T>(params MyCustomEnumerable<T> args) {
    foreach (var element in args) {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}

class MyCustomEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    List<T> _list = new List<T>();
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _list.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    public void Add(T tElement) => _list.Add(tElement);
}

then
Foo(1,2,3);

is compiled as:
MyCustomEnumerable<int> myCustomEnumerable = new MyCustomEnumerable<int> ();
myCustomEnumerable.Add (1);
myCustomEnumerable.Add (2);
myCustomEnumerable.Add (3);
Foo(myCustomEnumerable);

